# JavaScript countdown function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a countdown function, where the input is 10. Why do I get NaN from this code? I've tried different things and am not sure what works and what doesn't.

Here's my code.

```
function countDown(start) {

  if (start > 10 || start < 0 || start === 0){

    throw("Invalid");

  } else {

    let timer;

    for (i = start; i > 0; i--){
    timer += i; 
    }

    return timer;
  }
}
```

Trying to get the output "10987654321"

Comment: `let timer;` ... same as `let timer = undefined`; what happens if you `undefined + 1` - try initialising the value of `timer` ... to 0 perhaps? I don't know .. because after fixing that minor issue, calling this function with `5` would return `15` - oh, wait ... initialise timer to an empty string - seems you want to return a string

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, that fixed the NaN problem. but what if i want to set it to a string? what empty value would I have to use since i cant use 0? edit: ah yes, how would i be able to set it to an empty string?

Comment: use `''` - an empty string

Comment: @JaromandaX thank youu! problem's fixed

Comment: See my answer below, if you initialize it as an empty string, the numbers will append as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give `timer` a value before you can add another value to it.

`let timer = "";`

Answer (score 0):

You trying to add `undefined` value to number with this line `timer += i`.

you should to give value to the timer before using it.

**Solution**

```js
function countDown(start) {

  if (start > 10 || start < 0 || start === 0){

    throw("Invalid");

  } else {

    let timer = "";

    for (i = start; i > 0; i--){
    timer += i; 
    }

    return timer;
  }
}

console.log(countDown(10));
```